# I get an error when I try to retrieve the results from a php_mysql query.

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Khong the ket noi csdl!");
mysql_select_db("dream") or die("Khong the select database!");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");    
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list_console");
```

........

```
foreach (mysql_fetch_array($sql1) as $list) {           
    echo $list['name']
}
```

I want to echo a list of "name" in my database (list_console) but I get the following error:

```
Illegal string offset 'name' in ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that mysql_fetch_array returns false if there are no more rows. And you try to get the index 'name' from a bool.

Instead of this foreach use this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

If it's no more row $row will be false and while gonna stop.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql is not recommended as it already deprecated. try the following code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "database username";
    $password = "password (if any)";
    $dbname = "your database name";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_console";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["name"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

[php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: What was the problem and what is your solution?

Comment: problem is he don't php well and using backdate way of fetching data. I just showed him a way ...

Comment: ty man. that really help and its worked . but is there any way using foreach to echo my list ?  i want understand that too.